# Is there a way to have multiple completion suggesters on a single index?

Tags: elasticsearch

Here is my index:

```
{
"mappings": {
    "packages" : {
        "properties" : {
            "suggest-name" : {
                "type" : "completion"
            },
            "suggest-tags" : {
                "type" : "completion"
            },
            "suggest-cmdlets" : {
                "type" : "completion"
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

I would love to be able to something like this:

```
curl -XPOST 'localhost:32769/test/_search?pretty&pretty' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
    "suggest": {
        "packages-suggest" : {
            "prefix" : "get",
            "completion" : {
                "fields" : ["suggest-cmdlet", "suggest-name", "suggest-tags"]
            }
        }
    }
}
'
```

and specify all the fields I want to try to look at for the autocomplete.

This doesn't seem to be the right way to do it... How would you reference multiple fields in an autocomplete search query?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to do it like this:

```
curl -XPOST 'localhost:32769/test/_search?pretty&pretty' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
    "suggest": {
        "packages-suggest-1" : {
            "prefix" : "get",
            "completion" : {
                "field" : "suggest-cmdlets"
            }
        },
        "packages-suggest-2" : {
            "prefix" : "get",
            "completion" : {
                "field" : "suggest-name"
            }
        },
        "packages-suggest-3" : {
            "prefix" : "get",
            "completion" : {
                "field" : "suggest-tags"
            }
        }
    }
}
'
```

Comment: is there any alternative for the "prefix" clause?

Comment: @AliTwin Feel free to create a new question with your requirements.